# Does exist BSD's make syntax file?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

There are many make-variant, maybe the most popular is the [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). The vim package contains `syntax/make.vim` which related to GNU make.

Many people use different make, for example [FreeBSD's make](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)) which has different syntax than GNU make.

Does exist syntax file for BSD's make? And if yes, where?

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of syntax highlighting, GNU make and BSD make should be very close to identical. GNU make is a super-set of POSIX make (which is very close to what BSD uses), so there might be a few syntax highlighting options available for GNU make that you won't use with BSD make, but I don't think that you'll end up with any syntax in BSD make that's missing.

Comment: BSD make and GNU make differs! They have common part, the POSIX (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) but the another parts are different. The conditionals, for-loops, some assignments, built-in variables, variable modifiers, include statements (more than POSIX) are different (check the linked manpages please). The `syntax/make.vim` works well with GNU Makefile's conditional/for loops/... but not with BSD Makefile's conditional/for loops/....

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any ready-to-use solution so I began to write it. The actual version can find [here](https://svn.uzsolt.hu/homefiles/vimfiles/trunk/after/syntax/make.vim). It's only a complement to main `syntax/make.vim` so should place into `~/.vim/after/syntax` directory.